# Python mpi4py script segmentation fault on some nodes

Tags: python, distributed-computing, openmpi, mpi4py

A simple python mpi script crashes on particular nodes of the cluster with a segmentation fault.

The body of the script is:

```
import mpi4py 
mpi4py.rc.threads = False 
from mpi4py import MPI 
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
name=MPI.Get_processor_name()

print("hello world")
print(("name:",name,"my rank is",comm.rank))
```

I have tried loading all the modules in the batch files that I load before running the script on a single node, but that doesn't work. The sbatch file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --ntasks=256
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=150mb
#SBATCH -J jobname
#SBATCH --time=11:00:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=abc@xyz.com

module load python/3.6.4        
module load gcc             
module load openmpi         
module load mpi4py

echo $SLURM_NODELIST
echo $SLURM_NTASKS
echo $SLURM_JOBID
echo $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR
export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1

time mpirun --verbose -np $SLURM_NTASKS python3 testmpi.py
```

The first few lines of the output look like this the node's actual name is replaced by NODENAME and INSTITUTE is the placeholder for the place I work at:

```
[NODENAME:24753] *** Process received signal ***
[NODENAME:24753] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[NODENAME:24753] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[NODENAME:24753] Failing at address: 0x7f68a835a008
[NODENAME:24753] [ 0] /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf7e0)
[0x7f68a7f197e0]
[NODENAME:24753] [ 1] /usr/INSTITUTE/gcc/9.1-pkgs/openmpi- 
4.0.1/lib/pmix/mca_gds_ds21.so(pmix_gds_ds21_lock_init+0x124) 
[0x7f689d41c184]
[NODENAME:24753] [ 2] /usr/INSTITUTE/gcc/9.1-pkgs/openmpi- 
4.0.1/lib/libmca_common_dstore.so.1(pmix_common_dstor_init+0x983) 
[0x7f689d20ae43]
```

My guess is that modules aren't being loaded on these nodes.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It doesn't seem that your hello world code is wrong. Unfortunately we can't reproduce your issue if it only affects some nodes of a particular cluster. Thus the question is better addressed to the operators of the cluster.

Comment: I understand that, I was wondering if anyone has seen a similar segmentation fault and the libraries that show up in the traceback, my hunch is that some nodes are failing to call certain libraries that are failing, and if that is the case, how do i check it and fix it.